# Firebase.app() error when i try to implement auth

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

i'm trying to connect the DB to my App.js, it works, but when i try to do the auth, this error come out:

Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().
Ensure you have:

1. imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.
2. Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.

**This is my App.js before auth (working)**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

if (firebase.apps.length === 0){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <RestaurantNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
  }
}
```

**This is my App.js after auth (notWorking, see error of before)**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

if (firebase.apps.length === 0){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

function LoginApp(){
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  function onAuthStateChanged(user){
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Login</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <LoginApp />
        <NavigationContainer>
          <RestaurantNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </View>
    )
  }   
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hey @vale did you manage to find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add
In main application.java file
"import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;"
and in package
"packages.add(new RNFirebaseAuthPackage());"

[image]

And in android>app>build.gradle file in dependencies add
"implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0' "

[image]

Comment: But i've not those directories.. i'm using expo to run the app

Comment: Please check this link:
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/977

Comment: It is not usefull, i don't have those directories

Comment: I add those lines in other files with the same name but different roots, it still doesn't work

Comment: " import "firebase/auth" " instead of "import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'"

Comment: Now says that auth() is not a function